# how to get image from storage folder using tenancy laravel

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-5.6

Please answer,how to get image from storage folder using tenancy laravel.
[image]

Comment: we need more explanation.

Comment: How to create laravel storage:link custom path? I would like to point project/public/storage    >>     project/storage/app/tenancy/tenants

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here is my solution with Hyn 5.4 you can retrieve Current Tenant like this :

https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.4/identification#retrieve-current-tenant

```
 // Get current Website (Tenant)
 $website   = \Hyn\Tenancy\Facades\TenancyFacade::website();

 // prefered option
 $website   = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->tenant();

 // alternative (outdated) 
 $website   = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->website();

 $websiteId = $website->id;

 // Get current Hostname
 $hostname  = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->hostname();

 // Get FQDN (Fully-Qualified Domain Name) by current hostname
 $fqdn      = $hostname->fqdn;
```

You can access to the media by creating a route that will link to the 
 tenant media 

https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.4/structure#media

```
Route::get('/media/{path}', '\Hyn\Tenancy\Controllers\MediaController')
->where('path', '.+')
->name('tenant.media');
```

Comment: What's the best way to call / inject a custom model to the controller / view?

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna create custom storage disk, you can add inside your `config/filesystems.php`, under `disk` put this code.

```
'tenancy' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/tenancy'),
],
```

so you can access it with `Storage::disk('tenancy')`

e.g.

```
Storage::disk('tenancy')->get('tenants/64121.../images');
```